# How to implement pagination using Paging Library with RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I am using [**Paging Library**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) to make data from web API and works just fine with **RecyclerView** which is **not** inside **NestedScrollView**. But when I put RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView Paging Library requests data infinitely, so no paging happens as whole data is loaded at once.

Here is how layout looks:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frag_nested_scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:scrollingCache="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!--SOME OTHER LAYOUTS-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!--SOME OTHER LAYOUTS-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In activity:

```
    private fun getPosts(){
    val adapter = PostsAdapter {
        viewModel.retry()
    }
    recycler_view.adapter = adapter
    recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    //Other codes .....
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: did you solved your problem? if you have a solution, please help me!

Comment: @HoangLam Solving this was hard so I just ended using fragment with just recyclerView layout. So make separate fragment and fetch data from there.

Comment: wow! it looks like complicated

Comment: @HoangLam yeah but activity with Nested Recycler View and ViewPager may be and fragment with RecyclerView will do.